# Center box in already centred div

Tags: html, css

I'm using the following HTML / CSS to overlay a box on a website i'm working on. I want the box to center in the screen, not start based on the centering already going on. So basically the white box should be on the center of the page, not the text test

```css
.loading {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  overflow: show;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

/* Transparent Overlay */
.loading:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

.centrediv {
  height: 200px;
  width: 800px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="loading"><div class="centrediv">Test</div></div>
```

Comment: just coding it like this should center a div `<div style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto">` Here is the http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=BnpqDnjsf2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)`, `top: 50%` and `left: 50%` on `.centreDiv` to center it horizontally and vertically.

```css
.loading {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  overflow: visible;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
/* Transparent Overlay */

.loading:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.centrediv {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="loading">
  <div class="centrediv">Test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: or for older version browser support use `-ve` margin http://jsfiddle.net/r1r0fnxn/